# Would like to know how to find the min and max of a list Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have this program that calulates the avergae of grades. A teacher puts how many classes they want then how many students they want the program to run through. The program then asks them to import grades and calulates the average for them . I also want to add at the end the higest and lowest averages. Please help, thanks.

```
    classes = int(input("Enter the number of classes:"))
    for num in range(classes):
         students =int(input("Enter the amount of students:"))
         max1 = students
         total = 0
              for counter in range(max1):
                   number = int(input('Enter a grade:'))
                   total += number
              while number > 100:
                   print('Error: Grades must be less than 100')
                   number = int(input('Enter a grade:'))
              print('The total', total/ students)
    else:
         print('end')
```

Comment: a) You should pay attention to indentation. With Python, doubly so. b) You do not have a list. If you did, `max(l)` suffices.

Comment: How would i create a list that has all the averages in which i could compare them to each other to find the higest and lowest?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use lists: at start, `averages = []` to make an empty list, `averages.append(average)` to add one in each loop pass, `max(averages)` and `min(averages)` at the end.

If you don't want to use lists: `max_average = float("-inf"); min_average = float("inf")`, at each iteration `if average > max_average: max_average = average` (and equivalently for `min_average`).

Comment: Thanks how could i also print all the averages?

Comment: `for a in averages: print a` should suffice.